# Measuring distance travelled with android using Sensor Event Listener

Tags: android, android-sensors, sensor-fusion

I want to measure distance traveled using android with its sensor. Could you give me an idea how to start this project? Or give me any tutorials that would help me do this.

Comment: any solution you got?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an **ACCURATE** way to measure distance travelled using a Sensor Event Listener because the margins of error are huge. Check out this section of a video from GoogleTechTalks: [Sensor Fusion on Android Development](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k&feature=player_detailpage#t=1434s)

Instead, you just try using GPS to mark starting point and ending point and use a [Location Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) to measure the distance travelled.

Comment: What if I don't have any internet access? Will it still work?

Comment: Also, i'm measuring distance in kilometers.